# how to use ion-toggle in notification using ionic2 and angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Here  i am using toggle icon for setting notification active/inactive.i am getting response from get call.
In get call i am getting notification value either 0 or 1,but my ts file i am using noteValue is boolean means we are passing true are false.

But from database side we are getting either 0 or 1 ,database side they pass variable as boolean only,but database stored values as 0 or 1.

Because of noteValue toggle icon work incorrectly,means if i pass true or false when i refresh the app it(toggle icon) can shows false only.And if toggle icon is active it pass false value and toggle icon is inactive it passes true value.

html:

```
<ion-item no-lines  >
   <ion-label class="ion-label"> Notification</ion-label>
   <ion-toggle (ionChange)="updateValue()" checked="noteValue"></ion-toggle></ion-item>
```

.ts:

```
export class NotificationPage {
 public noteValue:boolean;  
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,private user:Users, private productServices:Products, private logger:Logger) {
    var _this = this;

// get call 
      this.productServices. getNotification(function(data){
         _this.logger.debug("checking my notification Details" +JSON.stringify(data));
         console.log(data.notification);
         _this.noteValue = data.notification[0];
         console.log(data.notification[0]);

      })

  }

//post call

updateValue(){
    var _this=this;

   _this.noteValue = !_this.noteValue; // If _this.noteValue is equal to true, now it will be set to false. If it's false, it will be set to true.

    let notificationDetails = {
      notification: _this.noteValue
    };
      console.log(notificationDetails);
      this.user.setNotification(notificationDetails, function (result, data) {
        _this.logger.debug("checking my notification Details" +data);
          if (result=='1') {
             console.log( _this.noteValue);
            //_this.noteValue=!_this.noteValue;
            _this.logger.debug("checking my notification Details" +data);
            alert("sucesscall for notification"+data.toString());
          }
          else {
            _this.logger.info("failure Notification");
            alert("failure for notification");
          }

          });

  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in DB you are saving value like 0 and 1, while the `ion-toggle` expects true or false, and you have to enable/disable it depending on these values.

If correct, with angular2 you can do something like this:

```
<ion-toggle (ionChange)="updateValue()" checked="{{your_DB_variable === 1 ? 'true':'false'}}"></ion-toggle>
```

And it will set true or false depending on `your_DB_variable`.

Hope I have helped you. :)